# SUM of rows with GROUP CONCAT and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, concatenation

I got a question regarding MySQL.

I got the following tables:

```
Invoices
invoices_ordermapping
invoices_positions
```

Invoices:

```
id | userid | state
1, 10, 1
```

invoices_ordermapping

```
id | invoiceid | orderid
1, 1, Order12
2, 1, Order13
```

invoices_positions

```
id | invoiceid | value | text
1, 1, 21, Example
2, 1, 18.9, Example 2
```

Now I would like to get the assigned orders to the invoice (Order12, Order13) and the total sum (Sum of value).

This is the result I expect:

```
Invoiceid | Orders | Sum
1, Order12, Order13, 39.9
```

I'm using this MySQL-Query:

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT orderid ORDER BY orderid SEPARATOR ", ") AS orderid, 
       SUM(ip.total) as value
FROM tbl_invoices as a
LEFT JOIN tbl_invoices_ordermapping as oi ON oi.invoiceid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_invoices_positions as ip on ip.invoiceid = oi.invoiceid          
GROUP BY oi.invoiceid
ORDER BY oi.invoiceid
```

Unfortunately I get this result:

```
Orderid: Order12, Order12, Order13, Order13
Value: 119.69999885559082
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like the following:

```
SELECT a.id AS InvoiceId, Orders, `Sum`
FROM Invoices as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoiceid,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT orderid 
                               ORDER BY orderid SEPARATOR ', ') AS Orders
           FROM Invoices_ordermapping 
           GROUP BY invoiceid ) AS oi ON oi.invoiceid = a.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoiceid, SUM(`value`) as `Sum`
           FROM Invoices_positions
           GROUP BY invoiceid) AS ip ON ip.invoiceid = a.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

The problem with your query is that `LEFT JOIN`s replicate `Invoices_positions` rows, and, as a result, `SUM` is calculated on multiple occurrences of the same rows of the table.

You need to perform aggregation first, for both `Invoices_ordermapping` and `Invoices_positions` tables and then join to `Invoices` table.

[**Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49cc0/1)